# WebSocket in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, websocket, utf-8

hello there i am trying to implement websocket in my app it was connected and i received the response but the data coming is in bytes and i am not able to configure how i convert and use that data i am stuck from last 2 days please help thanks in advance

response from socket

```
[0, 2, 0, 44, 0, 6, 58, 1, 0, 1, 109, 85, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 111, 97, 0, 115, 224, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 114, 0, 1, 115, 169, 0, 1, 116, 18, 0, 1, 108, 121, 0, 1, 113, 241, 0, 44, 0, 13, 128, 1, 0, 0, 55, 200, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 55, 227, 5, 172, 149, 3, 0, 0, 84, 154, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 79, 0, 0, 57, 28, 0, 0, 54, 226, 0, 0, 56, 89]
```

there are some rules defined by the websocket provider to use it but don't know how to configure in flutter

A   The first two bytes ([0 - 2] -- SHORT or int16) represent the number of packets in the message.

B   The next two bytes ([2 - 4] -- SHORT or int16) represent the length (number of bytes) of the first packet.

C   The next series of bytes ([4 - 4+B]) is the quote packet.

D   The next two bytes ([4+B - 4+B+2] -- SHORT or int16) represent the length (number of bytes) of the second packet.

C   The next series of bytes ([4+B+2 - 4+B+2+D]) is the next quote packet.